# Material Design - Form Tabbing on "Switch" checkbox?

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, user-behavior, material-design

I have a form that a user typically uses tab index to navigate throughout. I've updated most of the forms from standard checkboxes to "switches" with either a yes/no.

[image]

*label changed for IP...*

With Material Design I haven't been able to find information on "tabbing" and was wondering:

**Should a user be able to tab over the inputs and change their state, or explicitly have to click to change the state?**

Comment: You've stated that the user can navigate through tabbing on your form. Why would the switches be different? Is there a particular context they are being used in that might warrant different behavior than the rest of the form?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> is typically used to move from element to element, not to change the state of the element.

<kbd>Space</kbd> is generally used for simple binary state changes of the kind you described.

As an example, assume the user is focused on the first element of a form with a two-state switch as the fourth element defaulted to state 'A', the switch can be switched to state 'B' by hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd>.

I believe this can be disabled in cases where you might actually want the user to make a 'positive click' rather than casually tabbing through the form.

Most accessibility requirements include the provision of facilities for users who cannot operate a mouse which would normally be covered by the <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> functionality. Turning these off is almost certain to harm your accessibility rating. It's probably not mentioned in Material because it's inclusion is presumed as a standard accessibility facility.